# how to deal with graph theory related problems using perl

Tags: perl, graph, graph-theory

I want to learn how to solve simple graph theory problems in perl without using any extra module.
I can explain a simple problem.

Input format:
Line 1- number of vertices of graph-N.
Next N lines- index of vertices with direct connection to vertex with index i. Index starts from 1.
index of starting point (space) index of end point, find longest route possible.

Example

```
4  
2 3 4  
1  
1 4  
1 3  
2 4
```

Solution:

```
2 to 4 can be reached in following ways  
- 2-1-4  
- 2-1-3-4  
so longest path is 2-1-3-4
```

I want to learn the basics of using perl for such problems. Any help would be highly appreciated. Give me a hint and i will try to code.

Comment: Can a vertex be repeated in the path (but not an edge)?

Comment: edge should not be repeated. Anyways, my purpose is to not get this issue solved, i want an approach towards working with such problems using perl.

Comment: Do you mean `1-2-3-1-2-4` is not allowed for the graph `1-2, 2-3, 3-1, 2-4`, as `1-2` is repeated?

Comment: see the input, 4 means 4 vertex, next input 2 3 4 means we have edges 1-2 1-3 1-4, next input 1 means we have edge 2-1, next input 1 4 means we have edges 3-1 3-4, similarly 1 3 means we have 4-1 and 4-3. last input 2 4 means, find longest path from 2 to 4. So clearly we dont have any edge 2-3.

Comment: I just listed the edges (a different graph) as showing lines in comments isn't possible. But if you insist: `4 / 2 3 / 1 3 4 / 1 2 / 2 / 1 4`.

Comment: problem is to find longest route from 2 to 4, so i start with 2 and finds that only one edge from 2 ie 2-1. next i move to 1 and find edges 1-2 1-3 1-4, so i can now take either 1-3 or 1-4(no point going back to 1-2). So, i have reached from 2 to 4 via 2-1-4. Taking other route ie 2-1-3 from 3 i have edges 3-1 and 3-4. No point going back by taking 3-1, so i can take 3-4. So 2 to 4 can be reached by 2-1-4 and 2-1-3-4. CLearly 2-1-3-4 is longer that 2-1-4. I want this solution in using PERL.

Comment: Please, read my comments again. I'm asking for a more detailed specification. What should be the answer for the input I specified in my previous comment? Could it be `1-2-3-1-2-4`?

Comment: no, it should be 1-3-2-4, no edges repeated. i already replied that i my second comment. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a hash of hashes to represent a graph. `$graph{$v1}{$v2}` exists if the edge `v1-v2` is in the graph. You can represent directed graphs this way (as `$graph{$v2}{$v1}` doesn't have to exist). Also, if you want weighted edges, you can store the weight as the value.

To solve your example problem, I'd use something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

# Check that vertex can be added to the path.
sub already {
    my ($vertex, @vertices) = @_;
    for my $i (1 .. $#vertices) {
        # last-v or v-last might already be present.
        return 1 if ($vertices[ $i - 1 ] == $vertices[-1] and $vertices[$i] == $vertex)
                 or ($vertices[ $i - 1 ] == $vertex and $vertices[$i] == $vertices[-1])
    }
    return
}

sub path {
    my ($graph, $start, $end, %known) = @_;

    my $count = keys %known;
    for my $path (keys %known) {
        my @vertices = split '-', $path;
        next if $vertices[-1] == $end;

        for my $target (keys %{ $graph->{ $vertices[-1] } }) {
            undef $known{"$path-$target"} unless already($target, @vertices);
        }
    }

    if (keys %known > $count) {
        return path($graph, $start, $end, %known)

    } else {
        return keys %known
    }
}


my %graph;

my $size = <>;
for my $node (1 .. $size) {
    my @targets = split ' ', <>;
    undef $graph{$node}{$_} for @targets;
}
my ($start, $end) = split ' ', <>;

say "$start to $end can be reached in the following ways";
my @paths = grep /-$end$/,
            path(\%graph, $start, $end, map {; "$start-$_" => undef }
                                            keys %{ $graph{$start} });

say for @paths;

my $max = 0;
for my $i (1 .. $#paths) {
    $max = $i if ($paths[$i] =~ tr/-//) > ($paths[$max] =~ tr/-//);
}

say "so longest path is $paths[$max]";
```